# Connect two Android devices via router

Tags: android

I want to send data from one Android device to another Android device which are connected to same router via wifi?
Same App is installed on both devices and i want them to communicate each other connected to same router via wifi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - communicating between two devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608832/android-communicating-between-two-devices)

Comment: @FlorianKoch we have make use of Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer?

Comment: please clarify, I'm not sure what you mean. The answers of the other question also include information regarding connection via a router, not only direct, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26955220/3326982)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use socket connection with any of these protocols UDP, TCP or HTTP

**Send message using UDP**

```
String messageStr="Hello Android!";
int server_port = 12345;
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.102");
int msg_length=messageStr.length();
byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message,msg_length, local,server_port);
s.send(p);
```

**Receive UDP message**

```
String text;
int server_port = 12345;
byte[] message = new byte[1500];
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(server_port);
s.receive(p);
text = new String(message, 0, p.getLength());
Log.d("Udp tutorial","message:" + text);
s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in this (sending data between two devices on a wireless network connection without internet), so I did a quick search and found another answer below.

[Android - communicating between two devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608832/android-communicating-between-two-devices)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26955220/6589689

> Android Wireless API will also work if your devices are on the same 
>   local network (i.e., use the same WiFi router)

Comment: please don't answer only with links. Looking at your Link, the question seems like a duplicate - this means this question should be marked as duplicate instead of beeing answered (I know you can't do that just yet)

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are the way to accomplish this.

You'll need a way to discover the ip address and port of the socket you want to connect to. You can use Android network service discovery.

You can find a complete tutorial of how to build an app like this [here](http://brendaninnis.ca/connect-nearby-devices-part-2.html)